# Detect whether WordPress plugin is present

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there a way to detect whether a plugin is present in WordPress and output conditional code?

Here is why I want to do that...

I'm using the WordPress SEO Yoast plugin, and need to change the default title tag to get it to work properly e.g.

```
<title>
    <?php
        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    ?>
</title>
```

Needs to be changed to ...

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

That's fine, but what if I uninstall SEO Yoast at some point and forget to switch the code back? To be safe I'd like to have some conditional code that says..

If the SEO Yoast plugin is present, change the title code, if not, output the default title code.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `is_plugin_active` function (In the front end, in a theme, etc)

```
<?php 
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    If (is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php')) {

        //plugin is activated
    }
    else
    {
        //plugin is not activated
    }
?>
```

[**More here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active).

**Update:**

```
<?php
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    if (is_plugin_active('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php')) { 
        ?><title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title><?php
    } else {

        ?><title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title><?php
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Here's the final code for anyone else who has the same issue... <?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
 <?php
  if (is_plugin_active('wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php')) {
 ?>
      <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
 <?php
  } else {
 ?>
   <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
 <?php
  }
 ?>